# How does this method invocation with Arity-1 work in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and Spark. I wrote the program below which works fine. However I do not understand how it works. Any help will be appreciated.

```
object MyFirstSparkProgram extends App {
  def filterString(string : String) : Boolean = {
    string.contains("Python") || string.contains("Spark")
  }

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val rdd = sc.textFile("README.md").filter(s => filterString(s)) 
   // I understand this 

  val rdd1 = sc.textFile("README.md").filter(filterString(_)) 
   // I understand this

  val rdd2 = sc.textFile("README.md").filter(filterString) 
   // I know this works, but do not understand how does it work. 
   // The filterString method is defined with an argument(String),
   // how its called successfully without an argument?
}
```

My understanding of Scala is that if a method has no arguments it can be called without parentheses. (http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html), however my method `filterString` has an argument. How is it being called without parenthesis? The link above has an example for Arity-1, however it was not helpful to me.

Comment: It isn't an invocation.

Answer (score 2):

2 and 3rd examples are essentially equal, it's just `Function1[String, Boolean]` (=> is a sugar)

```
val f1: String => Boolean = filterString(_)
val f2: String => Boolean = filterString
```

You are not calling the function, you are passing reference to it

Answer (score 1):

If you use a method name of a method that needs explicit arguments, and don't supply enough argument lists (i.e. zero instead of one), and use that bare name where a function value is expected, the compiler converts such expressions to the function value of the appropriate type:

```
scala> def f(i:Int) = 5
f: (i: Int)Int

scala> List(6).map(f)
res1: List[Int] = List(5)

scala> (f(_)) andThen f
res9: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val x: Int=>Int = f
x: Int => Int = <function1>
```

It only works in certain contexts, in others you may need to use `(_)`:

```
scala> val y = f
<console>:8: error: missing arguments for method f;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       val y = f
               ^
scala> val y = f _
y: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f andThen f
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method f;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              f andThen f
              ^
```

This design decision allows you treat methods like functions where it makes sense.